# react-native-navigation createMaterialBottomTabNavigator hide tab from tabBar

Tags: react-native, tabs, navigation, react-native-navigation

I need your help :) I use createMaterialBottomTabNavigator and need to hide specific screen tab from bar :)

her is my navigation config`

```
  export const tabNavigation = [
      {
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeNavigation,
      },
      {
        name: 'History',
        component: HistoryNavigation,
      },
      {
        name: 'QrScanner',
        component: QrScannerNavigation,
      },
      {
        name: 'Payments',
        component: PaymentsNavigation,
      },
      {
        name: 'CardInfo',
        component: CardInfo,
      },
    ];
```

here is navigation`

```
<Tabs.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: RGB(colors.white, 0.0),
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        display: mainMenuState ? 'none' : 'flex',
      }}
    >
      {tabNavigation.map((nav, index) => {
        const { name, component } = nav;
        return (
          <Tabs.Screen
            key={index}
            name={name}
            component={component}
            options={{
              tabBarVisible: false,
              title: '',
              tabBarIcon: (tabState) => {
                return (
                  <SvgIcon
                    fileName={tabState.focused ? name.toLowerCase() + '-active' : name}
                    width={26}
                    height={26}
                    icon={true}
                  />
                );
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Tabs.Navigator>
```

so how can i hide card info tab from tab bar?

please help !!!!